# Group Model elements by Date in Table using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable, html-table

I'm trying to generate multiple tables from a model based on a datetime value. This is what I have so far:

```
@{
    DateTime prev = new DateTime();
    bool first = true;
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        DateTime now = item.StartDate;
        // If the current item is a different date to the last one, start a new table.
        if (prev != now)
        { 
            // But if it's not the first entry, it has to close the previous table first.
            if(!first)
            {
                </tbody>
                </table>
            }

            first = false;

           // New table starts.
           <h2>@now.ToString("D")</h2>
           <table>
               <thead>
                    <tr><th>item1</th><th>item2</th><tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               //With entry of this iteration.
                   <tr> <td>@item.item1</td><td>@item.item2</td><tr>
        }
        else 
        {
            //Otherwise just add another row to the current table
            <tr> <td>@item.item1</td><td>@item.item2</td><tr>
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I can't type closing table html tags (at least, in Visual Studio 2013), without the opening tags first. I've tried having:

```
if(first)
{
    //Create the first part.
}
else
{
    </tbody>
    </table>
    // Create the first part here instead.
}
```

But not only does this break the DRY principle, but it doesn't work for the same reason mentioned above.

I had thought that this would have been a simple enough task. Either I'm missing something, or I've had some oversights. Either way, any help would be greatly appreciated. If anything here isn't clear, please let me know and I'll happily clarify.

This is the expected result, for clarity:

```
Wednesday 25 March, 2013
Item1       Item 2
Infohere    Infoheretoo
Infomore    MoreInfo

Thursday 26 March, 2013
Item1       Item2
OhYeah      MoreInfo!
OhLook!     Yup, MoreINfo!

Friday 27 March, 2013
Item1      Item2
Ithink     YouGet
ThePoint   Here....
So         I'm
gonna      stop...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it better by making your code a little bit cleaner.

```
@foreach(var group in Model.GroupBy(x=>x.StartDate))
{
  <table>
  @foreach(var item in group)
  {
     //render rows

  }
  </table>
}
```

If you are not concerned about the readability, you can always use `@Html.Raw("</table>")`.

Comment: That was perfect bud. Thanks so much. I was trying to group using a separate query and then iterating through that, and it worked, but this is much tidier. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks alot for above example it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Razor doesn't like having missing or mismatched HTML tags, even if they are split up by conditional logic (i.e., between `if`/`else` blocks). You can bypass this be writing out the mismatched tags with an additional colon after the Razor `@`, e.g.:

```
@:</table>
```